# mac mail slow with allot of emails, best way to optimise ?

Tags: mail.app, email

Ive got mac mail running on my macbook pro (2.7ghz i7, 16gb ram, 1gb dedicated gpu) using OSX 10.10.5

It seems to be very slow of late, in general operations and in searching, i presume this is down to the amount of emails i have which are divided up between 9 accounts, all of the accounts are connected to via imap or in the case of google apps for business accounts using the inbuilt mail.app google apps / gmail account setup which i presume builds an imap connection in the back end. (see below for details on accounts).

The accounts go back in places up to 5 or 6 years, and i was wondering if its possible in mail.app to keep some of the data for the larger account online only and if that would speed up mail. Or if there is any other way to better manage this quantity of emails.

- account 1 : c. 45gb of email and attachments, hosted with google apps for business
- account 2 : c. 5gb of email and attachments, hosted with google apps for business
- account 3 : c. 5gb of email and attachments, hosted with web host
- account 4 : c. 5gb of email and attachments, hosted with google apps for business
- account 5 : c. 2gb of email and attachments, hosted with google apps for business
- account 6 : c. 2gb of email and attachments, hosted with google apps for business
- account 7 : c. 2gb of email and attachments, hosted with web host
- account 8 : c. 15gb of email and attachments, hosted with google apps for business
- account 9 : c. 2gb of email and attachments, hosted with google apps for business

Comment: What is the setting of Mail Preferences-> Account tab-> Account's Account information -> Download Attachments ?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii it was set to "all" but i think i found the solution. I was using an HDD on this computer at the time when i wrote the above question. Ive since upgraded to an SSD and its allot quicker. I think the problem was to do with searching for emails, the HDD couldn't preform quick enough.

Comment: Glad! Please close the question!